# Gestures not working on FT5336

Tags: i2c, touchscreen, compute-module-3

I'm new to the CM3+ module, but I've worked extensively with other RPi products.

I'm currently trying to implement my own FT5336 driver, but I'm having some slight problems, as the "Gesture" register address always returns 0.

I'm not the only person with that problem, as I've noticed that [other people](http://www.nhdforum.newhavendisplay.com/index.php?topic=6490.0) have had problems with this exact touch controller as well. It has been suggested that I contact the manufacturer, but they require information about the business and their [direct contact](http://www.focaltech-systems.com/en/contact/onlineMessage.html) information probably isn't meant for troubleshooting or support.
At first I thought that I was doing something wrong and was supposed to write/send a command to the chip before reading the gesture, but after looking at [other drivers](https://github.com/focaltech-systems/drivers-input-touchscreen-FTS_driver/blob/add4c56dfa95137b22675a359cc0af7936bcddc3/ft5x06.c#L776), all they do is read.

Now I'm not sure if this is even the correct place to post this, if it isn't please let me know, so I can move it somewhere else.

My setup:

- CM3+
- Wondershare Compute Module IO Board Plus
- Capacitive touch screen with FT5336 controller connected over DSI and I2C(-11?) (pins 28 and 29)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I cannot have a reading for the gestures no matter what I do!!

side note though, I changed the mode of the interrupt from trigger to polling and it is much better to have an interrupt that only triggers the isr on falling edge and rising edge(when the touch start and the touch ends) and in between you can read via I2c as mush as you need and you have full control.

Things that just doesn't work with me so far:

1. Gestures
2. touch point weight(touch pressure)
3. touch point Area

let me know if you have an update or if you figured out the gesture problem.

Comment: We've figured out that Wondershare has sent us a chip without gesture support, so we changed it for a different one. Our Wondershare did have a register for touch point area.

Comment: Oh, OK. So they actually ship some of these without having the feature!!

Comment: Sadly yeah, if I remember correctly, registers for gestures weren't saving any settings I've set. Try doing the same and check if it's the case with you as well.

Comment: Just tried to set all the registers for min distance and max offsite and all of them are set correctly(I read them after to verify). are there any more settings I should apply ?
Since you managed to make it work could you share with me the settings you used on the working  project?.. and also I'm curious to know when do you  read the gesture, after the touch points are lift up ?.. or is the gesture ID could be red before that ?

Comment: Currently the project is on hold. We switched to another touchscreen chipset. I'm a tad hazy on details, as it was more than half a year ago, sorry .

Comment: I could, however try getting the same touchscreen and device back for testing, but that will have to wait until monday.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help. whenever you have time and could dig out anything I would be grateful :)

Comment: Ok, I'm really late with my reply, but I've enquired about the display, but it's no longer available to me. We've exchanged it for a GT911 chip. I can try to see if I could salvage it and try to make it work on a home raspberry pi, but that'll be another few days. How's the progress on your side?